# google app engine task queue don't complete in production but complete in devserver

Tags: django, google-app-engine, task-queue

when running some google app engine tasks on dev server it completes with 200 status, but when deploying and running the same task on production the task don't get executed completely and get retrying until it use all retry count.

I think this may be something with task timeout, and increasing it may fix my problem but can't figure out how to do so!!!

BTW i used

> print >>sys.stderr

to trace my code execution progress and every time the code stops at the same point

Comment: If it's failing, it's failing for a reason. What do the logs show? Are you getting an exception? Also, don't use print - use `logging.error` or `logging.exception`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since execution always stops at the same point, this is unlikely to be a timeout. Your application might be trying to do something that is not permitted in the App Engine sandbox.